# How can i get webservice XML with JavaScript

Tags: java, xml, http, get

How can i use Java Script with HTTP Web service, this is the HTTP get request:

```
 'GET /stockquote.asmx/GetQuote?symbol=string HTTP/1.1
  Host: www.webservicex.net
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
  Content-Length: length

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <string xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">string</string>'
```

i have found this Java on stack but i cannot get it working:

```
 '$.get(
  "somepage.php",
  {paramOne : 1, paramX : 'abc'},
  function(data) {
   alert('page content: ' + data);
  }
  );'
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason the code you found isn't working is that it's wrapped in single quotes and it depends on a third-party library called [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).  If you link to jQuery from your page (and remove the single quotes around the jQuery string) and point to the right URL in the $.get method with the right parameters, it will probably work fine.

Comment: Thanks adv12, i was hoping for something a little more constructive. Yes, i have a JQUERY library reference in my code and the Quotes are required to post code on stackoverflow. if you have any helpful comments i will be greratful.

Answer (score 0):

I completed this in C#

```
 'Using System.Net;
```

Using System.IO;

```
public class GetData
{
    public static string HTTP_GET(string Url, string Data)
    {
        string Out = String.Empty;
        System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Url + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Data) ? "" : "?" + Data));
        try
        {
            System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
            using (System.IO.Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    Out = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    sr.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            Out = string.Format("HTTP_ERROR :: The second HttpWebRequest object has raised an Argument Exception as 'Connection' Property is set to 'Close' :: {0}",
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            Out = string.Format("HTTP_ERROR :: WebException raised! :: {0}", ex.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Out = string.Format("HTTP_ERROR :: Exception raised! :: {0}", ex.Message);
        }

        return Out;
    }
}

[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string getQuote()
      {  
        XmlDocument quoteXML = new XmlDocument();
        string strQuote =       GetData.HTTP_GET("http://www.mywebservice/stockquote.asmx/GetQuote", "symbol=lloy.l");
    return strQuote;
      }'
```